# What is the ratio of hearts to damage numbers?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

How much numeric damage is a heart? How can I tell if I'm on track for A-rank when the mission complete screen has numbers and the in-battle screen has hearts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the sources I've seen](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/745183-hyrule-warriors/70191737), 100 damage is 1/4 heart, and one heart is 400 damage. 4,000 damage (the usual cutoff for A rank, though it varies) is therefore 10 hearts.